# Filling in gym membership prices by joining PANDAS dataframes

Tags: python, performance, datetime, pandas, join

I have two dataframes, `df` which contains a list of members in addition to the type of contract that they purchased on a given date, `df` is about 10 000 entries. I have another `df_prices` which contains the average price of a given contract for a given year and month.

`df` resembles:

```
    Member Nbr      Date-Joined         Contract Type
1           1        2010-03-31     1 Year Membership
2           1        2011-04-16     1 Year Membership
3           1        2012-08-06     1 Year Membership
4           1        2013-08-21     1 Year Membership
5           1        2014-08-31     1 Year Membership
6           2        2015-09-03     1 Year Membership
7           2        2012-12-10     4 Month Membership
8           2        2013-03-13     1 Year Membership
9           3        2014-03-15     1 Year Membership
10          3        2010-02-09     1 Year Membership
...
10095    7374        2016-02-29     1 Month Membership
10096    7375        2016-03-01     1 Year Membership
10097    7376        2016-03-01     1 Month Membership
10098    7378        2016-03-04     1 Month Membership
10099    7379        2016-03-06     1 Month Membership
10100    7380        2016-03-05     1 Year Membership
10101    7387        2016-03-10     3 Month Membership
```

and `df_prices`

```
          Date                   Description      Amount
0   2010-01-31            1 Month Membership   54.036316
1   2010-01-31             1 Year Membership  325.000000
2   2010-01-31            4 Month Membership  147.642353
3   2010-01-31            7 Month Membership  227.890000
5   2010-02-28            1 Month Membership   55.283846
6   2010-02-28             1 Year Membership  333.250000
7   2010-02-28            4 Month Membership  146.257358
8   2010-02-28            6 Month Membership  165.000000
9   2010-02-28            7 Month Membership  223.905714
10  2010-02-28                     Pool Only  250.000000
...
462 2015-12-31            4 Month Membership  146.390000
463 2015-12-31            6 Month Membership  204.815000
464 2016-01-31            1 Month Membership   45.037143
465 2016-01-31             1 Year Membership  265.000000
466 2016-01-31            3 Month Membership  112.927273
467 2016-01-31            4 Month Membership  147.413333
468 2016-01-31            6 Month Membership  204.093333
469 2016-02-29            1 Month Membership   45.699444
470 2016-02-29             1 Year Membership  265.000000
471 2016-02-29            3 Month Membership  110.285556
472 2016-02-29            4 Month Membership  139.477500
473 2016-02-29            6 Month Membership  202.650000
```

I have written some code in python that fills a list based on a customers join date and contract type and adds it to `df`, which is exactly what I want. The problem that I'm facing is that is is extremely slow to finish, and was hoping for some help to optimize it, especially as I plan on using a this on a larger dataset.

Here is what I have:

```
#### Standard Libraries ####
import time

#### Third-party libraries ####
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def Main():
    start = time.time()
    location = '/home/lukasz/Documents/Xtreme Fitness/Members/AllMembers.xlsx'
    location2 = '/home/lukasz/Documents/Xtreme Fitness/' + \
                'AverageContractPrice.xlsx'

    df = pd.read_excel(location)
    df_prices = pd.read_excel(location2)
    df_prices.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

    prices = []

    for i in range(len(df)):
        df_date = df.loc[i, 'Date-Joined'].year * 1000 + \
                  df.loc[i, 'Date-Joined'].month
        df_contract = df.loc[i, 'Member Type']

        for j in range(len(df_prices)):
            if (df_prices.loc[j, 'Date'].year * 1000 + \
                df_prices.loc[j, 'Date'].month == df_date and 
                df_prices.loc[j, 'Description'] == df_contract): 

                # print("%s, %s" % (i, df_prices.loc[j, 'Amount']))
                prices.append(df_prices.loc[j, 'Amount'])

    prices
    df.to_excel(location, index=False)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Looking at the code and the description, it looks like that what is called "contract type" in `df` description is called "member type" in the code. Is that so? If yes, can you edit question so both match?

Comment: Also you don't seem to modify `df` at all in the for loop, so what is the purpose of writting it back in an excell file?

Comment: There's also a line consisting of just `prices`, which doesn't do anything. Overall it seems like you have not been very careful with this code, and I'd be hesitant to get started on optimizing it until I could be confident that I understood what it's doing and that it actually works correctly.

Comment: @David Z, `prices` is a an empty list that gets append with the values of a given contract type from a given date. `prices` then gets added to `df`

Comment: @David Z to understand what is going on I have two separate excel files, one containing a list of members with the type of contract that they have purchased on a given date, and a second excel file with the prices of those contracts on a given date. Now I would like to include a column in my first file that contains those prices based on what type of contract they had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a [left side merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to match member data with corresponding prices by contract type and date. No `for` loops or external list needed for this approach:

```
df = pd.read_excel(location)
df_prices = pd.read_excel(location2)
df_prices.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

finaldf = pd.merge(df, df_prices, left_on=['Date-Joined','Contract Type'],
                   right_on=['Date','Description'],
                   how='left')[['Member Nbr','Date-Joined','Contract Type','Amount']]

finaldf.to_excel(location, index=False)
```